# Error in mle R function: L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Tags: r, normal-distribution, mle

I am trying to use MLE on my data in R, but I get this error and I don't know why:

> Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) :   L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

This is my code:

```
negative_likelihood <- function(mu, sigma){
    -sum(dnorm(my_data, mean=mu, sd=sigma, log=TRUE))
}

mle(negative_likelihood, 
                    start=list(mu=1, sigma=1), 
                    method="L-BFGS-B")
```

and this is my_data:

```
my_data <- c(4.94586, 6.12280, 4.81591, 5.50351, 5.50545, 5.15068, 6.16997, 5.46339, 5.06350, 5.51779, 4.56657,
6.29238, 5.34117, 4.91623, 5.32503, 4.89550, 5.96892, 5.53120, 5.39801, 6.52902, 6.39206, 5.40570,
5.05369, 6.25207, 6.22229, 5.07920, 4.86948, 5.27202, 5.87191, 4.67544, 5.29845, 6.61682, 5.84775,
6.23129, 5.64602, 5.47904, 4.86500, 5.73270, 5.04059, 5.32655, 4.94984, 5.21750, 5.49940, 5.80918,
5.62308, 5.17108, 5.30865, 4.68632, 6.08171, 4.97175, 5.01062, 6.11321, 4.87875, 6.44020, 5.40842,
4.62120, 6.32134, 4.66841, 5.15763, 4.94830, 5.42050, 5.60300, 6.41332, 5.84598, 5.43916, 6.26707,
5.77663, 4.86735, 4.72968, 4.75750, 6.09207, 4.86551, 6.61289, 6.12277, 5.67457, 5.35039, 5.03592,
6.06066, 5.36947, 5.24907, 6.19433, 6.24891, 6.22482, 5.45656, 5.67550, 6.05438, 5.72339, 4.78657,
6.28039, 6.25110, 6.41801, 4.91509, 5.78600, 5.20904, 5.00558, 5.50219, 5.21147, 5.11444, 5.00882,
6.47516, 6.38823, 5.24394, 5.33561, 5.54943, 6.45429, 6.39522, 6.48763, 5.64982, 4.66434, 5.34011,
5.63098, 4.67009, 4.96963, 6.15372, 6.58736, 5.53276, 5.48312, 5.93943, 5.75046, 5.24359, 5.85595,
5.97529, 5.68883, 5.06501, 4.99481, 6.30492, 5.36067, 5.85319, 4.56297, 5.00996, 6.40176, 6.48352,
5.61199, 5.71818, 6.39520, 5.39979, 5.87741, 4.69639, 6.18796, 5.97227, 5.92887, 4.94455, 4.85209,
5.02248, 4.98821, 5.48650, 6.33475, 4.54574, 4.98732, 4.80852, 5.57595, 6.51516, 5.64974, 4.58779,
5.03896, 4.65786, 6.29632, 4.94102, 4.52586, 4.76241, 5.66072, 4.72090, 5.71862, 5.26193, 6.33256,
6.04895, 4.48541, 4.68550, 5.03825, 5.97953, 6.01831, 5.02418, 6.27500, 5.95202, 5.59450, 5.36699,
5.66311, 6.04644, 6.25481, 4.72681, 6.55935, 4.78016, 6.27429, 4.85316, 5.68597)
```

Comment: @jared_mamrot
I don't know how to use normal distribution in this tutorial, because normal distribution has 2 parameter but this tutorial has 1 parameter(it's binomial)

Answer (score 3):

This error is happening because the parameters of your function are converging to values that return non-finite output from your function. Namely, if sigma = 0, the following happens:

```
> -sum(dnorm(my_data, mean=1, sd=0, log=TRUE))
[1] Inf
```

To get around this, you can specify a lower bound on estimates of sigma:

```
mle(negative_likelihood, 
    start=c(mu = 1, sigma = 1),
    method="L-BFGS-B",
    lower = c(-Inf, 0.01),
    upper = c(Inf, Inf))
```

This returns a sensible result:

```
Coefficients:
       mu     sigma 
5.5271686 0.5849431
```

Since `mean(my_data)` = 5.527, and `sd(my_data)` = 0.586, I'd say this is a good estimate.